# UIWebview fitting to screen but not zooming in iphone programming

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am working on uiwebview and it is supposed to load dynamic urls coming from the server.
i want to show it fitting to the iPhone screen size in my iPhone application and also it should zoom in and out.

Code i am using for it is:

```
m_pView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 430)];
    m_pView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.view = m_pView;

UIWebView *aWebView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 1, 320, 400)] autorelease];
    aWebView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
    aWebView.delegate = self;
    NSString* url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://%@",[m_URL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    aWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    aWebView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    aWebView.frame = self.view.bounds;

    NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString: url];
    NSURLRequest *aRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:aURL];
    //load the index.html file into the web view.
    [aWebView loadRequest:aRequest];
    [m_pView addSubview:aWebView];
    self.m_webView = aWebView;
```

Please let me know how to achieve webview fitting to the iphone screen size without loosing zoom in/out feature.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
 yourWEbView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    yourWEbView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Answer (score 0):

problem might be in this line:
aWebView.frame = self.view.bounds;

Why you're setting bounds of self.view while adding webview to m_pView?

Comment: do you think it has any relation with the zoom of the webview?? I tried setting  aWebView.frame = self.m_pView.bounds; and it has no effect yet.